# Mathematically lossless video conversion with FFMPEG and nvenc hevc?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, hevc

I take a linear gradient input in the range `[0, 255]`, where each next pixel is greater than the previous one by `1` rgb value.

[image]

[image]

Then I convert it to lossless video, input - `rgba(pc)`, output - `yuv444p(tv, progressive)`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i %01d.png -c:v hevc_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv444p -tune lossless out.mov
```

And back to the image, input - `yuv444p(tv, progressive)`, output - `rgb24(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive)`:

```
ffmpeg -i "out.mov" "img/out-%03d.png"
```

The result is not lossless, almost every pixel differs from the original by `-2...+2`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The same thing happens with other encoders, for example: `ffmpeg -y -i %01d.png -crf 0 out.mov`. Perhaps it is caused by the limited range of `tv`, how to set it to `full`? `-dst_range 1 -color_range 2` doesn't seem to be working. Maybe there is something else?

Comment: I don't think that NVENC supports lossless HEVC.  The `-tune` parameter is for libx264/libx265, and I don't see it documented for NVENC.  In either case, you're probably better off using the software codec in this case.  There's probably no benefit to the GPU here, yeah?

Comment: It does support Tuning information `-tune` https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introducing-video-codec-sdk-10-presets/ . `ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_nvenc` also has an option `-tune: hq, ll, ull, lossless`.

Comment: What happens if you add `-preset lossless` in addition to your current options?

Comment: @Brad Nothing. This is the same as `-tune lossless`. The problem is the tv range or the rgb-yuv conversion. Or something else.

Answer (score 0):

YCbCr to R'G'B' and back is not lossless and cannot be. 10 bit YCbCr is needed to preserve 8 bit R'G'B'.

Okay, first of all rgba (alpha in hevc) is only supported by Apple encoder in ffmpeg. Second of all, -vf format=gbrp should be used (you can just omit yuv444p mention). ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_nvenc shows supported pixel formats (compare to ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264rgb)
**Supported pixel formats: yuv420p nv12 p010le yuv444p p016le yuv444p16le bgr0 rgb0 gbrp gbrp16le cuda d3d11**

Also pix_fmt option is deprecated for use, besides rawvideo. Use pixel_format.

And instead of -dst_range 1 -color_range 2

You need -vf scale=out_range=pc:out_color_matrix=bt709 -color_range 2 -colorspace bt709